# Which dependency should be used to integrate Apache Camel with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

Apache Camel provides two ways to integrate with Spring Boot:

- camel-spring-boot
- camel-spring-boot-starter

When I look at the starter then I see that it only includes camel-spring-boot and spring-boot-starter. What is the difference then and what are the advantages of using starter?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment of writing this answer, `camel-spring-boot` is only supported from Camel 2.15 and `camel-spring-boot-starter` only from Camel 2.17, which is important considering the current version that your project is using.

Then the major difference between these two dependencies, lies in the "opinionated" auto-configuration provided by the starter.

- `camel-spring-boot`, should be used if you want just to include a jar to make your camel routes auto-discovered by spring boot, this also gives you the freedom to update this dependency regardless of your spring-boot version.
- `camel-spring-boot-starter`, **(recommended way to go)** should be used if you want a collection of dependencies (including camel-spring-boot) that provides the best developer/user experience, due to the fact of customizable properties, additional libraries, and default configuration for the camel library. Check the reference documentation for the starter: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/spring-boot.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration

#### Summary

- Use `camel-spring-boot`, if you want a vanilla jar to use camel with spring boot
- Use `camel-spring-boot-starter`, if you want an automatic-configured component to start to develop with.

Comment: What are the other dependencies in camel-spring-boot-starter than camel-spring-boot?

Comment: Just all camel related dependencies:

- spring-boot-starter
- camel-core-starter
- camel-core
- camel-spring-boot

References: 
- https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/platforms/spring-boot/components-starter/camel-spring-boot-starter/pom.xml
- https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/platforms/spring-boot/components-starter/camel-core-starter/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the `camel-xxx-starter` dependencies, as these are the Camel components that is support with Spring Boot. Also as mentioned they provide auto configuration and some of them additional capabilities.

If there is no `camel-xxx-starter` component then its because its not supported on Spring Boot with Camel.

See more at: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/platforms/spring-boot/components-starter#camel-component-starters